# How to encrypt an external SD card natively?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, security, encryption, adoptable-storage

There are several questions regarding the possibility to encrypt an external SD card on Android. None of them are satisfactory. They either point to a third party solution (e.g. [BoxCryptor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxcryptor2.android), [Cryptonite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=csh.cryptonite), [EDS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sovworks.eds.android), [LUKS Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nemesis2.luksmanager)) or refer to a ROM specific GUI-way to encrypt. So my question remains:

**How to encrypt an external SD-card with built-in kernel features?** There is support for [dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt) and [eCryptfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECryptfs).

---

For further reading:

- [What is encryption?](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/security/encryption/index.html)
- [Android + encryption on the G1 using cryptsetup and LUKS](https://androidvoid.wordpress.com/2009/09/30/android-encryption-using-cryptsetup-and-luks/)
- [How does Android filesystem encryption work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/56594/how-does-android-filesystem-encryption-work)

---

**EDIT:**

Since `Marshmallow` it is now possible to encrypt an external sd-card nativley with `aes-cbc-essiv:sha256` as an **adoptable storage**. Sadly, this makes the internal storage of an android device unusable. In the light of the recent changes introduced in `Android 6.0` I want to ask my question again and rephrase it:

**Is it possible to encrypt an external SD-card with aes-cbc-essiv:sha256 without using it as an adoptable storage?**

---

For further reading:

- [Decrypting Android M adopted storage](https://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2015/06/decrypting-android-m-adopted-storage.html)
- [Android 6 semi-adopted storage](http://blog.sam.liddicott.com/2016/02/android-6-semi-adopted-storage.html)
- [How to decrypt Adopted Storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/145443/how-to-decrypt-adopted-storage/145446#145446)
- [Corrupt SD card formatted as internal storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/135803/corrupt-sd-card-formatted-as-internal-storage/135836#135836)

Answer (score -1):

There is an option in Android 4.2.2 or higher that you can encrypt your SD Card on: Settings > Security > Encrypt SD Card. You need a screen lock to encrypt it. Once you do that, it will be encrypted.

[image: Sorry for the notification.]

Comment: This is what I meant as I was speaking from a 'ROM specific GUI-way to encrypt'. This option is just available in certain ROMs.

Comment: Okay... But I will update it if I find another.